# How to search inside of a LookupSet

Tags: reportbuilder3.0

If you do a LookupSet and it returns the values:

11/6/2014 3/17/2015 9/14/2015 2/27/2013

is there anyway to search those dates and return only the dates that meet certain criteria, such as year = 2015 and Month >= 7

Here is the code that gave me the above values:

Join(LookupSet(Fields!UNID.Value,Fields!Parent_UNID.Value,Fields!Inspection_Date.Value, "Inspections"))

Answer (score 0):

Only way I can think of doing this is an Iif() to change the date into something conspicuous and then a replace to delete them:

```
=Join(LookUpSet(Fields!UNID.Value, Fields!Parent_UNID.Value, Replace(Iif(Year(Fields!Inspection_Date.Value) = 2015 And Month(Fields!Inspection_Date.Value) >= 7, Fields!Inspection_Date.Value, "XXYYZZ"), "XXYYZZ", Nothing), "Inspections")
```

So what this does is checks if the Year of the date is 2015 and the month is >= 7 and if so, returns the date. If it's not, it returns XXYYZZ, and then the Replace() statement looks for that string and just returns it to nothing.